# Aligning divs vertically while keeping them ordered in a 'list-style'

Tags: css, html, alignment

I've come to a point where I really can't think of any solutions for this problem anymore. What I want to achieve is:
I fill content in some divs, for example values from 0-10. Then, when showing them, they should be listed in a way that's responsive to the users window size. 
On A Big screen it should look like this:

```
1 | 4 | 7 | 10
2 | 5 | 8 
3 | 6 | 9
```

And on a smaller Screen:

```
1 | 5 | 9
2 | 6 | 10
3 | 7
4 | 8
```

I tried it by giving the divs the `float: left;` Property, which gives me an output like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
5 | 6 | 7 | 8
9 | 10
```

Problem is: the order is not the same as in the expected output, and: the 'rows' are being filled first, not the cols. 
Does anybody know a solution how one can achieve something like this with only css and html?

Comment: Do you mind posting your html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern solution is CSS Multi-column module. You could use it like this:

```
.content {
    -webkit-column-width: 80px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EN92F/

Check [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn), IE10+.

If it is not supported by the browser (IE8 for example) it will gracefully degrade to single column layout, like here http://jsfiddle.net/EN92F/1/, which is not that bad.

Further reading [Using CSS multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multi-column_layouts).