# How to leave default float's value of first 6 elements, and make the rest floated left?

Tags: html, css

I'm converting PSD mock-up to HTML and CSS, and now I'm stuck a bit. I'm sure most of you have faced very similar issue, since that type of presentation is very popular in the web.

As you can see on footer's image, I'm trying to represent elements this way using only one block. And I want that block to look like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
       ...The rest ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And that's the problem. I can't put that all into one block.

I'm currently having them all in 5 different (in 5 different `navs` with `ul` elements ) blocks and that works. But would be very painful to render content for back-end developers (5 `foreach` iterations!)- and that's the reason I want to put them all in one block.

[image]

Is this even possible? I couldn't find anything useful so far

Comment: Yes, this is CSS columns.

Comment: @dfsq Yes I've heard that too before, but couldn't find anything useful. Can you provide an example or a link?

Comment: It would be nice to have the full set of HTML and the CSS you've tried. You can use the Stack Snippets feature to include it in the question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409627/aligning-divs-vertically-while-keeping-them-ordered-in-a-list-style/15409838#15409838

Comment: @bad_boy just to ask that Paris should be below Rome, right?

Comment: @sdcr Yes exactly. Each item must be `block`-like element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct use here would be CSS Columns.

Browser compatibility: Modern browsers, and IE10+ http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

```css
.columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  column-count: 5;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <p><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></p>
  ... The rest ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take that list and just break after every 5 items.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rome, Italy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Paris, Frace</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li:nth-of-type(5n):after {
    display:block;
    content:"";
}
```

**DEMO:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/sLLua6xh/)

Comment: For the record, this has partial support back to IE8 - http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aafter